# .NET AWS Lambda with Mediator

Tags: .net, lambda, architecture, clean-architecture, mediator

we want create new application with aws Lambda. We normally use Mediator, clean architecture and controllers. Is it ok use mediator with lambda? Because we have common logic like pipeline behaviours, validations etc. And i don't know if it's good plan. Because every lambda functions must build many dependencies. Is it ok or it's better create "normally" api?

Thank you

Comment: I would argue that it is pretty much ok. Using Mediator can have some performance overhead but in most scenarios it is negligible (though you should measure it yourself, but in upcoming .NET 7 AOT should reduce some of it). Though you should consider if it's infrastructural overhead is not a problem for you project. Depending on lamdas logic and coupling it can be.

Comment: I think it isnt problem for my project. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see any problem with mediator in lambda but keep lambda size smaller to reduce cold start or use lambda layer.